# Sendgrid e-mail blocked by host provider

Tags: java, sendgrid

Im using sendgrid JAVA API (**version 2.2.2**) to send e-mails from my webapp.

My customer host provider is blocking my E-mail requests and they told me that they allow just in a specific port.

From sendgrid docs I found this:

> Many hosting providers and ISPs block port 25 as a default practice. When trying to connect to smtp.sendgrid.net remember that ports 25, 2525, 587, and 465 are all available for use. You can connect via unencrypted or TLS on ports 25, 2525, and 587. You can also connect via SSL on port 465. Keep in mind that many hosting providers and ISPs block port 25 as a default practice. If this is the case, contact your host/ISP to find out which ports are open for outgoing >smtp relay.

**I need help to understand how can I change the default port from JAVA API.**

Comment: sendgrid-java 2.2.2 uses HTTP to send emails, not SMTP, so something else is happening rather than a blocked port.

Comment: This is the error status from sendgrid: REASON554 5.7.1 Blocked by URIBL https://admin.uribl.com/

Comment: I dont know but maybe the host provider don't allow HTTP Requests

Comment: That's a spam blacklist. If you're getting any status from SendGrid, that means your host isn't blocking anything... otherwise nothing would ever make it to SendGrid. Sounds like you have other issues. I suggest reaching out to SendGrid support.